# how does ld deal with code that is supplied twice (in a source file and in a library)?

Tags: gcc, g++, shared-libraries, ld, linkage

Suppose we call

```
gcc -Dmyflag -lmylib mycode.c
```

where `mylib` contains all of `mycode` but is compiled without `-Dmyflag`. So all functions and other entities implemented in `mycode` are available in two versions to the loader. Empirically, I find that the version from `mycode` is taken. Can I rely on that? Will `mycode` always overwrite `mylib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Empirically, I find that the version from mycode is taken.

Read [this explanation](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking/) of how linker works with archive libraries, and possibly [this one](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

> Can I rely on that?

You should rely on understanding how this works.

If you understood material in referenced links, you'll observe that adding `main` to `libmylib.a` will invert the answer (and if `mycode.c` also contains `main`, you'll get duplicate symbol definition error).

If you are using a dynamic library `libmylib.so`, the rules are different, and the library will always lose to the main binary, although there are many complications, such as `LD_PRELOAD`, linking the library with `-Bsymbolic`, and others.

In short, you should prefer to *not* do this at all.